# how to put multiple graphs in same graph having same y aix range but varying x axis in R

Tags: r, graphics

Data set 1:

```
0.8519685   1
0.8400882   1
0.8464  1
0.8428793   1
0.8438172   1
0.8416375   1
0.8475025   1
0.8296616   1
0.8415241   1
0.8577903   1
0.8654286   1
0.8591148   1
0.8352778   1
0.8508564   1
0.8199912   1
0.8440318   1
0.8161487   1
0.8592727   1
0.850286    1
0.8563889   1
0.8585333   1
0.854275    1
0.8418394   1
0.8315148   1
0.8040112   2
0.7881706   2
0.78821 2
0.7818517   2
0.7773207   2
0.7817786   2
0.769675    2
0.7681707   2
0.7568771   2
0.7822226   2
0.7774829   2
0.7894815   2
0.7744519   2
0.7782154   2
0.7394333   2
0.7749136   2
0.7497919   2
0.7928364   2
0.7887512   2
0.8072222   2
0.78303 2
0.8209792   2
0.7590879   2
0.7787667   2
0.8447202   3
0.8406627   3
0.831145    3
0.8319397   3
0.8370069   3
0.8103875   3
0.8024688   3
0.8127556   3
0.8072374   3
0.8147936   3
0.8389314   3
0.8404519   3
0.8145204   3
0.8214462   3
0.7823491   3
0.8034705   3
0.7878973   3
0.8193091   3
0.8240977   3
0.8301389   3
0.8144933   3
0.8180958   3
0.7862212   3
0.8342704   3
```

Data set 2:

```
0.8551  2001
0.8626  2001
0.716   2001
0.8455  2001
0.847   2001
0.794   2001
0.8144  2001
0.7992  2001
0.7794  2001
0.8121  2001
0.8364  2001
0.8778  2001
0.8698  2001
0.872   2001
0.8775  2001
0.8226  2001
0.8226  2001
0.8226  2001
0.8049  2001
0.783   2001
0.8611  2002
0.8738  2002
0.7886  2002
0.8762  2002
0.8797  2002
0.844   2002
0.7166  2002
0.841   2002
0.8069  2002
0.8393  2002
0.8323  2002
0.8771  2002
0.8748  2002
0.8748  2002
0.8704  2002
0.836   2002
0.8403  2002
0.8162  2002
0.8429  2002
0.828   2002
```

Main question:
how to put multiple graphs in same graph having same y axis range but varying x axis?

Further explanations:
First column of both datasets area containing values of CELL while for "data set 1" second column is "category" while for "data set 2" second column is "year". I want "cell" in Y axis while "category" and "year" in "x-axis". Many thanks

I want category to be lined up and/or stacked with year in box/whiskers.

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to do with this?  It's easy enough to plot two sets of different data in the same space, but how do you want them lined up or differentiated?  Do you want "category" to line up with "year - 2000"?  Without more of an explanation, this really feels like something that should either be a categorical comparison (i.e. box and whisker plot) or be two separate plots in order to be readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another solution which might be helpful.

```
data1 <- read.table("data1.txt")
data2 <- read.table("data2.txt")
names(data1) <- c("cell","category")
names(data2) <- c("cell","year")
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
meltdata1 <- melt(data1, id=c("cell"))
head(meltdata1)

meltdata2 <- melt(data2, id=c("cell"))
comb <- rbind(meltdata1,meltdata2)
head(comb)

ggplot(comb, aes(x=factor(value), y=cell))+geom_boxplot()+facet_wrap(~variable, scales="free_x")+xlab(" Category / Year")
```

Output of this is as follows:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something:

```
datasetcomb<-rbind(dataset1,dataset2) #combine datasets

#V1 is cell, V2 is another variable

boxplot(V1~factor(V2),data=datasetcomb,at=c(1,4,7,2,5),ylab="Cell",
    xlab="Category/Year",xaxt="n",col=c(3,3,3,2,2))
axis(side=1,at=c(1,4,7,2,5),labels=c(1,2,3,2000,2001))
```